# Framework7 + Vue + Firebase: Open an individual page displaying the dynamic info from the database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, html-framework-7

How to I get to open a user with a dynamic url each to an individual page?
I use Framework7 + Vue for a Cordova Project.
I have customized the default product page that grabs an id and display data of a single product, It works by generating the unique ID (“uid” as per firebase) for each user in a url by it fails to pass it the user.vue page that I created, it doesn’t open when I click on it. What exactly could I be missing here? I don’t know much about JSON.stringify stuffs!

user.vue - the individual data page

```
<f7-page name="user">
        <f7-navbar :title="user.username" back-link="Back"></f7-navbar>
        <f7-block-title>About {{user.username}}</f7-block-title>
        <f7-block strong>
            {{user.email}}
        </f7-block>
</f7-page>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            var userId = this.$f7route.params.id;
            var currentUser;
            this.$f7.data.users.forEach(function (user) {
                if (user.user_id === userId) {
                    currentUser = user;
                }
            });
            return {
                user: currentUser,
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

home.vue - the user list loop, working just fine as expected

```
<f7-list>
    <f7-list-item
            v-for="(user) in users"
            :key="user.user_id"
            :title="user.username"
            :link="`/user/${user.user_id}/`"
    ></f7-list-item>
</f7-list>
```

home.vue - mounted functions script

```
mounted() {

let viewUsers = this;
const usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
usersRef.on("value", snapshot => {
  let data = snapshot.val();
  let users = [];
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    users.push({
      id: key,
      username: data[key].username,
      user_email: data[key].email,
      user_id: data[key].uid,
    });
  });
  viewUsers.users = users;
});
}
```

home.vue - data returned script at the top

```
data() {
return {
users: this.$f7.data.users, //the arrays had already been called/initialized at the app.vue
}

routes.js:

import UserPage from ‘…/pages/user.vue’;

{
path: ‘/user/:id/’,
component: UserPage,
}
```

What exactly am i missing here?

Comment: did you find it?